# What is the behaviour if sensitivity label for all users is published (via policy) for a subset of users?

Tags: azure-purview, microsoft-information-protection, azure-information-protection

Suppose I create a sensitivity label with encryption so that only organizational users can access the file. Say there are 100 users in the organization.

And then I create a policy that publishes this label to only a subset of organizational users. Say for 10 users only.

In this scenario, only 10 users can apply the sensitivity label. And also are able to view the file.

What about the remaining 90 users? They won't see the label in options (so they aren't able to apply sensitivity label) but what is the encryption behaviour? Can they view the file?